# Finding liquid viscosity

Tags: measurements, liquid

I'd like to calculate the viscosity of a liquid in a container systematically (and feed the results back to a computer). I only have basic knowledge of physics and mechanics.

I think that a motor with a tiny "windmill" constantly turning inside the liquid would be enough because someone one could measure the current and voltage being supplied to the motor and then *somehow* link that back to the force which the motor is putting in. I'm hoping that there's a formula to link force and volume of liquid moved to viscosity.

Does this sound like a good approach and if not, why?

If it is a good approach, how would I go about calculating liquid viscosity from the original data and what sorts of measurements would need to be taken?

Comment: Viscosity is one of the more difficult property measurements. Check out the more typical ways its measured here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscometer. What fluid are using?

Comment: You will need to identify Newtonian, thixotropic and rheopectic fluids...

Comment: And this should be interesting : https://smp.uq.edu.au/pitch-drop-experiment

Comment: No matter which approach you take, calibration will be very difficult.  You'll need to maintain pressure and temperature precisely, and try to trace well-known fluids back to published values for their viscosities.

Comment: @ericksonla interesting- the fluid is mostly water with some additions that change its viscosity

Comment: @SolarMike ahh I remember being shown that in my Physics class a couple of years ago (discussing whether states)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I see but taking underwater temperature and pressure measurements wouldn't be an issue